# NullPointerException with a class using Gdx.files.internal() during test (maven version)

Tags: java, maven, junit, libgdx

I've been trying for a while to get some JUnit tests to work in a project using the *Maven* version of Libgdx, but did not manage to succeed.

In my project I have a class that handles the audio for my game. For now the class is quite simple, and does not do much more than looking for an audio file in a folder, and playing it. I use the Gdx.app.internal() to get the file that I need, and it workd perfectly fine when running the game.

Now when I write a test file, which is in the root/core/target/test-classes/.... folder, the Gdx.app.internal() immediately throws an exception. When using FileHandle.exists(), it returns true when running from the game, but false when I run it from tests.

My guess is that it might have to do with some dependencies that Libgdx needs, and when running the game normally all is set for you. Thus I tried looking up some other topics that discuss this, but did not manage to find much information about it.

So to summarize my question: Is it allowed to call for Gdx.files.internal() in a JUnit test case? If not, what is the best way to go about testing classes in your Libgdx project?